# Choose different column on SELECT if one is empty

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with two columns (well, two columns that concern this question) - pub_date and update_date.  pub_date always has a date, and update_date is empty unless the row was updated.  Is there any way to use a SELECT call to return update_date, but fall back to pub_date if update_date is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[`coalesce`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)** function

> The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not
>   null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null

```
select coalesce(update_date,pub_date),update_date,pub_date
from yourtable
```

Comment: Of course!  I just learned the COALESCE function like a month or two ago and already forgot about it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` Statement:

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN 
               update_date IS NULL OR 
               update_date='' 
           THEN pub_date ELSE update_date 
      END AS update_date 
FROM YourTable
```